# Why isn't a reverse iterator a formal iterator category according to the C++17 standard?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

Reverse iterator is not on the list of iterator category tags, so assumedly it is not a category. So what is it exactly?

Comment: Why would this need a tag? It makes no difference to the _user_ of the iterator whether its a reverse iterator or not. Some iterators don't even have a direction at all.

Comment: I suppose my main question was what exactly a reverse iterator was classified as. While I don't have a need right now for such a tag, I can envision data structures where you might want to traverse in a different order (say for cache locality purposes) depending if you are going forward or backward.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The iterator categories encode *levels of functionality*.

- An input iterator is the bare minimum floor - incrementable and dereferenceable *once*
- A forward iterator is an input iterator that you can dereference multiple times and has multipass support.
- A bidirectional iterator is a forward iterator that you can decrement
- A random access iterator is a bidirectional iterator that you can O(1) advance by +/- `n`
- A contiguous iterator is a random access iterator that refers to contiguous memory

Those levels of functionality are used by algorithms - some algorithms *require* a certain level of functionality, some algorithms can simply optimize based on certain levels of functionality (e.g. `advance(it, n)` for random access iterators can just do `it += n` whereas for forward iterators it has to be `++it` in a loop).

But "reversed" isn't a level of functionality - it's just a different way to present the underlying data. A reversed iterator doesn't merit its own iterator category for the same reason a "move" iterator doesn't or a "filtered" iterator doesn't or a "counted" iterator doesn't. Algorithms don't care if the iterators are reversed or not - they work the same way either way. It's not important which way `++it` actually moves the iterator.

Reversed iterators are just iterators. [`std::reverse_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) is known as an *iterator adapter* (along with a bunch of others, like [`std::move_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator)) - it's an iterator that adapts a different iterator. But you could write a reverse iterator that is not an adapter - indeed, you could even write a reverse iterator that isn't bidirectional! These two concepts are orthogonal.

Comment: "*A contiguous iterator is a random access iterator that refers to contiguous memory*" The Range system effectively defines contiguous iterators as random access iterators that can be converted (via a function) into `value_type*`s that cover the same range. Which implies that they refer to some portion of a contiguous array.

Comment: @Nicol Not sure where you got that from. [`ContiguousIterator`](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.contiguous) is directly specified to refer to contiguous memory. The conversion to `value_type*` is `addressof(*it)`.

Comment: When I said "effectively", I mean in terms of something that can actually be *detected* by a concept, rather than assumed due to a tag. Being bidirectional means being able to do `--`. The equivalent behavioral difference would be conversion to pointers, the way that ContiguousRange requires that you can apply `range::data` to it. However, I thought that `to_address` had been adopted for ContiguousIterators in C+20 at the most recent meeting, but apparently it was not.

Answer (score 8):

> so assumedly it is not a category.

Your assumption is correct. Reverse iterator is not a category of iterators.

> So what is it exactly?

Standard defines `std::reverse_iterator` as:

> Class template reverse_iterator is an iterator adaptor that iterates from the end of the sequence defined
>   by its underlying iterator to the beginning of that sequence. The fundamental relation between a reverse
>   iterator and its corresponding iterator i is established by the identity: &*(reverse_iterator(i)) == &*(i
>   - 1).

The iterator category of `std::reverse_iterator<Iterator>` is the iterator category of `Iterator`.

---

Similarly, other iterator adaptors such as move iterators, filter iterators, striding iterators etc. are also not iterator categories.